# API to get all available Tasks/Bugs etc for a Project in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I Want REST API Url to get all available tasks/bugs/epic etc. for given project. I have tried below URL but does not return me anything

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{projectname}/_apis/wit/workitems
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This url `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{projectname}/_apis/wit/workitems` does not work as work item list.

You can try to use WIQL: [Wiql - Query By Wiql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1). [Example for tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#examples):

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=5.1
```

Body

> {
>
> "query": "Select [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.State] From
> WorkItems Where [System.WorkItemType] = 'Task'
> AND [System.TeamProject] = 'Your_Project' order by [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority]
> asc, [System.CreatedDate] desc"
>
> }

Here is WIQL documentation to create your own query: [Syntax for the Work Item Query Language (WIQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/wiql-syntax?view=azure-devops)